# Best way to get data from a Server to Android phone

Tags: android, xml, json

I would like to write an Android application which communicates with central server written in php , communicate with it and get/send data, for example user authentication, display of user preferences etc.
My question is what is the best way to do it. Use a webservice at the server side which returns an xml and parse the xml at the android or use json , or use a html post response back and parse it.
Any help on it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: json... easier to use and more flexible

Answer (score 9):

Json is the the best option

because It's light way and can easily converted in to java object.
In short JSON is the best

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I have one more question what should i used at the server side to genearte the JSON.

Comment: although I am not a web developer, hear is the link for php... http://www.sencha.com/learn/legacy/Tutorial:Creating_JSON_Data_in_PHP

Answer (score 2):

As other answers said, JSON. It is lightweight, its easy to use, android has standard libraries which support JSON.

example:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
JSONArray projects = new JSONArray(_webService.getStringResponse());
int counter = 0;
int projectSize = projects.length();

while(projectCount < projectSize) {
    JSONObject projectData = projects.getJSONObject(projectCount);

    values.put(DbProperties.PROJECT_ID, projectData.getString("pid"));
    values.put(DbProperties.CUSTOMER_ID, projectData.getString("cid"));
    values.put(DbProperties.SETTLEMENT, projectData.getString("settl"));
    //Do some database saving for example

    counter++;
}
```

What happens here(took this out of an app so you get the idea) is as follows:

I post a request, get some result back in JSON format. I create an JSONArray object which takes a json string as constructor parameter, in my case, the json string consists of an array that contains json objects

I loop through each item in the JSONArray, create a JSONObject and then extract data from the json object and save it to the database.

My goal with this simple example is to show a few things;

- its incredibly easy to work with JSON in android
- easy to compress the string by simply shortning the key names(json is basically key-value paired).

The latter has the benefit of chunking down the size of the string being said, while as a con, the data is less readable. I did this for compression reasons, and my code is very well commented. To reflect this compression.

Answer (score 1):

please use json. XML is too huge. html is not designed for data exchange.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on client as well as server team. In android nice `JSON` API is available. it is easy to parse incoming data and prepare request in `JSON` format.

Though you can also go for `xml`. nice upport available for `xml` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend JASON. Its a defacto standard these days. And not so heavy like XML.

I've been using many C# JASON webservices fr my ANdroid applications and they all work like charm. I'm sure it'll be same with PHP services too.

Posting HTML response will be ok for a form but for a complex data you'll have hard time.

So I'll vote for `JASON`.

Also have a glance over this [supplementary read](http://www.devwebpro.com/in-favor-of-json-over-xml/).